# What is the meaning of "By when do you need a decision to join the next cohort? "?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I saw this question in [an application form](https://apply.joinef.com/application/1268486), but couldn't understand what does it mean?

> By when do you need a decision to join the next cohort?

Comment: I edited your question to add the link you provided in the comments. It didn’t take long after that for your question to get an up-vote and a proper answer. In the future, you should include where you found the sentence you’re asking about. There is some good advice for writing questions in this post on [meta]: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, a cohort is a group of people who join the course at the same time.

The website explains

> Some individuals have visa requirements (which we can support with), or long notice periods. If this is the case please make a note here and we can expedite your application.

A decision, in this context is the decision that "Entrepreneur First" make about whether to accept or reject your application.

So it may be that you need to know the result of your application early, so you have time to apply for a visa, or tell your employer that you are quitting your job. If a visa takes 6 weeks to process (for example) you need to know the result of the application 6 weeks in advance, so you have time to get the visa. Here you can write the date by which you need to know the result of the application.